# Weka SMOreg and LIBSVM with linear kernel problems

Tags: weka, regression, svm, libsvm, menpo

I want to test a dataset in weka using either LIBSVM with an e-SVR or SMOreg for regression.
I also choose a linear kernel in both (in SMOreg i use an exponent=1 in a non normalized polykernel).

After cross-validation the root mean squared error (rmse) as well as the mean absolute error return  both are equal to **NaN**.

Is this supposed to be an error in the values of the dataset I use (it contains no missing values)...
How can I possibly handle this ?
Any hints on what should I check ?
The data I use for training are the appearence and shape parameter values of an Active Appearence Model created with Menpo.io using python...

Comment: for the record I have replaced any Inf or NaN values that were present the dataset with the mean of each column (dimension)

Comment: I also addressed this over on Reddit. If you want to have a really detailed discussion, can I suggest that you post on our mailing list over at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/menpo-users?

Comment: Thanks, I have created a much more detailed thread at  groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/menpo-users
as you suggested